# SOQL to query only records with Max(createdDate) for each quarter

Tags: apex, soql

I have a set of records which get generated on a daily basis which gives some totals of sales which is generated by another apex.

I need to query for only records which have the max(createdDate) for each quarter. I am not sure of how to approach the Max(createdDate) in the where condition

```
SELECT  Sum(_ARR__c),
                                            Sum(Influenced_Count__c),
                                            Sum(Sourced_ARR__c),
                                            Sum(Sourced_Count__c),
                                            Quarter__c, // This is a date
                                            Sum(TotalARR__c),
                                            Sum(TotalCount__c) 

                                    FROM    Marketing_Impact__c 
                                    WHERE   Quarter__c != null 
                                    AND     Max(createdDate) // Here is what i need help on
                                    GROUP BY Quarter__c
```

**UPDATE**

How do we approach it on apex if we cant do a direct query?

Comment: please include what you have tried.

Comment: Are you trying to find the `MAX(CreatedDate)` or find out other information on the record with that value?

Comment: @AdrianLarson its finding out other info about the record for those Max(createdDate)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know such things is not supported by SOQL, try to use ORDER BY CREATEDDATE DESC

Comment: How do we approach it on apex if we cant do a direct query?